# ¿Cómo integrar buscar en la actionBar Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Quiero hacer lo siguiente, tengo un icono en la `ActionBar` con la lupa (lo muestro en la imagen) y cuando se clickea la lupa quiero que cambie a la otra vista (segunda imagen) y que se pueda escribir en el action bar

[image: 1]

*(Segunda imagen)*
[image: 2]

Comment: No hay "segunda imagen" puedes colocarla por favor?

Comment: la primer imagen es la negra, la segunda imagen es la azul

Comment: El componente se llama SearchViews, Puedes seguir ese tutorial para integrarlo http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solucion, se las dejo en el siguiente link
http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/